# Using Lambda as a Parameter (Python)

Tags: python, parameters, lambda

So I'm taking a Python class in college right now and have run into a bit of a problem ... this is my current code:

```
def both(firstFunction, secondFunction: bool):

    return True if firstFunction == True and secondFunction == True else False

def is_even(number):

    return True if number % 2 == 0 else False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    check = both(is_even, lambda x : x <= 100)    
    print(check(2))
```

The error I'm getting right now is **Type Error: bool object is not callable**. I believe the error is originating with the lambda call, since when I replace the second parameter in **check** I get no problems. How exactly does lambda work then? I thought it simply assigns a name that references a function that doesn't need to be defined.

Comment: can you show us the traceback from the error?

Comment: why do you have `secondFunction: bool` in the definition line of `both`?

Comment: and you realize you're not calling `firstFunction` or `secondFunction` inside `both`, right?  you're testing whether the functions themselves are `True`, which I believe they always will be.

Comment: the error raised by the code you've provided is a `SyntaxError` -- for the bad definition line for `both` -- not a `TypeError`.  and this question has nothing to do with `lambda`, so please edit the title.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issues you could change your both function to:

```
def both(firstFunction, secondFunction, *args, **kwargs):
    if firstFunction(*args, **kwargs) and secondFunction(*args, **kwargs):
        return True
    return False
```

Then call both using:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print both(is_even, lambda x: x <= 100, 2)    
    print both(is_even, lambda x: x <= 100, 98) 
    print both(is_even, lambda x: x <= 100, 102)
```

Results:

```
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Andrew's answer, but maybe more concise:

```
def both(first, second, *args, **kwargs):
    return first(*args, **kwargs) and second(*args, **kwargs)

def is_even(number):
    return number % 2 == 0

print(both(is_even, lambda x: x <= 100, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `both()` function is returning a boolean. You are assigning the return value of `both()` to `check`, then attempting to call `check` as a function (which it isn't, it's a boolean value).

Secondly, your `both()` function doesn't call `firstFunction` and `secondFunction` at all. You are trying to compare the functions themselves to `True`. The only (built-in) values in Python that are equal to `True` are `True` and `1` (for historical reasons). Functions are never equal to `True`.

What you probably want, guessing from your function names, is either Andrew's or Rain's answer.

Alternatively, if you actually want `both()` to return a function, you can do something like this instead:

```
def both(first, second):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return bool(first(*args, **kwargs) and second(*args, **kwargs))
    return inner
```

Then you can call `both()` like in your question.

PS: Why have you annotated the `secondFunction` argument in your `both()` definition with `bool`?

Answer (score 0):

Auscom nailed it. I didn't know it at the time, but my professor had asked me to write a function that had a function within it. I had no idea how to do it at the time, but then I realized it after Auscom posted. Thank you!

This was my final code;

```
def both(first, second):
    def inner(*args):
        return bool(first(*args) and second(*args))
    return inner
```

Then it would be used as this:

check = both(is_even, lambda x: x <= 100)

check(2)

- Returns True